# How can we add sheets dynamically with a particular template in excel using excel interop in C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

```
  Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
  Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Template.xls");
  Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
  xlWorkSheet = excelfile.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
         {
some operations performed in the sheet
}
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(@"D:/Outputs/" + "Result.xls");
```

This is what I am doing, I need to create / add more sheets with the same template in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend you recording a macro in Excel with required action. Then copy/paste the VBA code to your app and edit it as required (most edits can be performed by find and replace).